# Cloud function -> comparing timestamps

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to make a cloud function where the function deletes every item in the "links" collection where the "eindTijd" (endtime) timestamp is older than now.

The function executes on every DB write, and gives me no errors at all, but just doesn't do what I intend to do. It's driving me nuts!

I suspect the error is in the oldItemsQuery, but cannot find out what goes wrong. Any help would be really appreciated!

The "eindTijd" field is generated with a Date function and is recognized to be a valid timestamp in Firestore.

```
  'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);

exports.verwijderOudeNodes = functions.firestore
.document('/links/{pushId}')
.onWrite(() => {
  const now = Date.now();
  let oldItemsQuery = firestore.collection('links').where('eindTijd', '<=', now);
  return oldItemsQuery.get().then((snapshot) => {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    let batch = firestore.batch();
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
      batch.delete(child.ref);
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return batch.commit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to log the size of the QuerySnapshot with: `return oldItemsQuery.get().then((snapshot) => {console.log(snapshot.size); ....`?

Comment: When you're having problems like this, always first try to reproduce the problem in a standalone node script. If you can reproduce the same problem with that, you know it's not related to Cloud Functions. If you can't reproduce it in standalone, you know it *is* related to Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the way you're passing `now` is correct. Based on the [Firebase documentation on writing its various data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types), I'd expect:

```
const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
```

Comment: This was what did it! Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: Or you can just pass `new Date()`, which will get automatically converted to a Timestamp.

Comment: @Doug: I was wondering about that, but then saw that the docs contains this more complex example. Sounds like we should add more samples there. :)